# How to setup yarn client in code?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform

I want to run my spark application on my hortonworks data platform. As in this setup I don't have a spark master standalone I want to run as a yarn client.

I am trying to create the SparkSession like this:

```
SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("yarn-client")
    .appName("my-app")
    .getOrCreate())
```

I know I am missing some properties to let spark client where my yarn server is running but I can't seem to find those properties.

Currently the app just hangs init with no error or exception.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to run your app locally while your Hortonworks HDP is somewhere else.

> Unlike Spark standalone and Mesos modes, in which the master’s address
>   is specified in the --master parameter, in YARN mode the
>   ResourceManager’s address is picked up from the Hadoop configuration.

So your app should be run from Hortonworks itself, which has all the Hadoop configuration in place.

Comment: Sergey, do you mean it's not possible to run a remote client from outside of hdp? It is usually possible when running against spark master. Can you share a reference for this? And if so, is it recommended to start s standalone spark master under hdp to overcome this limitation?

Comment: You can run a remote client outside of HDP. But you have to set up all the Hadoop environment variables to match your HDP.

Comment: Can you share a link that points to all the needed variables?